# Displaying all data from text file

Tags: c#, if-statement

When the user types in 'day' the if statement should run and display all the data from the text file, but for some reason it only prints the first line 'Monday' but really it should print:

'Monday
Friday
Thursday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Monday
Friday
Thursday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Monday
Friday'

How do I fix this?

(Also if the user types, for example, 'day' the else statement still writes how do I fix that?)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //int ctr = 0; 

        string[] dayData = File.ReadAllLines("Day.txt");
        string[] dateData = File.ReadAllLines("Date.txt");
        string[] sh1CloseData = File.ReadAllLines("SH1_Close.txt");
        string[] sh1DifferenceData = File.ReadAllLines("SH1_Diff.txt");
        string[] sh1OpenData = File.ReadAllLines("SH1_Open.txt");
        string[] sh1VolumeData = File.ReadAllLines("SH1_Volume.txt");

         Console.WriteLine("Which array would you like to view?");
         string input = Console.ReadLine(); 

          if (input.ToLower() == "day")
             Console.Write("\n{0}", dayData);

          if (input.ToLower() == "date")
             Console.Write("\n{0}", dateData);

          if (input.ToLower() == "close")
             Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1CloseData);

          if (input.ToLower() == "difference")
             Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1DifferenceData);

          if (input.ToLower() == "open")
             Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1OpenData);

          if (input.ToLower() == "volume")
             Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1VolumeData);

         else  
            Console.Write("\nSorry, you entered an invalid term, please enter: day, date, close, difference, open or volume.");

         Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be one entry in the arrays for each line found in the files. You're doing something odd by passing the entire array to the `Console.Write` method, whose second parameter is being interpreted as your string format arguments. Since you only have one format index ("{0}"), you only see the first item in the array.

To see *all* the entries separated by spaces, change each condition to:

```
if (input.ToLower() == "day")
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', dayData));
```

I would further improve your application to only load the file that is needed based on the entered item. You reduce file I/O and remove unnecessary CPU/memory usage. This could be much easier to maintain by doing something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // map expected inputs to their corresponding files
    var inputMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "day", "Day.txt" },
        { "date", "Date.txt" },
        { "close", "SH1_Close.txt" },
        ...
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Which array would you like to view?");
    string input = Console.ReadLine(); 

    // Make sure there was input and it's in the map; get it if it is
    string filePath;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || !inputMap.TryGetValue(input.ToLower(), out filePath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you entered an invalid term, please enter: day, date, close, difference, open or volume.");
        return;
    }

    // Make sure the file exists
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // read all lines from the file
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        // join them with a space and output to console
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', fileLines));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the file doesn't exist.");
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question has been answered by the above answer, but as for your second question

> Also if the user types, for example, 'day' the else statement still writes how do I fix that?

You have a bunch of single line if statements, and then the last if statement also has an else.  So the way that code is written, you'll always print the else, unless the user typed "volume".  If you wanted to really only print the else if none of the handled inputs was entered, you'd need to do this:

```
if (input.ToLower() == "day")
    Console.Write("\n{0}", dayData);

else if (input.ToLower() == "date")
    Console.Write("\n{0}", dateData);

else if (input.ToLower() == "close")
    Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1CloseData);

else if (input.ToLower() == "difference")
    Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1DifferenceData);

else if (input.ToLower() == "open")
    Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1OpenData);

else if (input.ToLower() == "volume")
    Console.Write("\n{0}", sh1VolumeData);

else  
   Console.Write("\nSorry, you entered an invalid term, please enter: day, date, close, difference, open or volume.");
```